# Android : Can't show the package name of installed app inside Android/data/<package name>

Tags: android

This is my manifest file
    i dont think there is a anything wrong in java file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.abd.xyz" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">

      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
      <application
          android:allowBackup="true"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
        <activity

            android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity"

            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
          <meta-data
              android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
              android:value="true" />
        </activity>

      </application>

    </manifest>
```

App is running well but in Myfile/android/data/ there is no package name of that installed app

Answer (score 2):

You can not see the content of `Android/data/<package name>` unless your device is rooted.

Content of `Android/data/<package name>` is not visible to user.

Comment: I have run other app also. & I see the package name of that app in Android/data/<package name> as well. So please help me , m very much stuck over here.